# Display a graph inside GUI using Python, PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to create a graphical interface with pyqt5 and when I press the button "capteur1" I want to display data in a graph as shown on the figure below, using PyqtGraph or matplotlib.

[image]

Im using Qt designer to create the GUI.

Code generated by qt designer:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

import picturs_icons_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1051, 763)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(43,31,91);")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.main_header = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_header.setObjectName(u"main_header")
        self.main_header.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.main_header.setStyleSheet(u"QFrame{\n"
"   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
" border-bottom: 1px solid #000;\n"
"}")
        self.main_header.setFrameShape(QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.main_header.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.main_header)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.tittle_bar_container = QFrame(self.main_header)
        self.tittle_bar_container.setObjectName(u"tittle_bar_container")
        self.tittle_bar_container.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.tittle_bar_container.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.tittle_bar_container.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tittle_bar_container)

        self.top_right_boutton = QFrame(self.main_header)
        self.top_right_boutton.setObjectName(u"top_right_boutton")
        self.top_right_boutton.setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215))
        self.top_right_boutton.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton{\n"
"  border-radius:5px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"  background-color:rgb(0,92,157);\n"
"}")
        self.top_right_boutton.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.top_right_boutton.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.top_right_boutton)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.minimise_button = QPushButton(self.top_right_boutton)
        self.minimise_button.setObjectName(u"minimise_button")
        self.minimise_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.minimise_button.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/images/images/icons8-minimize-window-26.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.minimise_button.setIcon(icon)

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.minimise_button)

        self.restore_button = QPushButton(self.top_right_boutton)
        self.restore_button.setObjectName(u"restore_button")
        self.restore_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.restore_button.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon1 = QIcon()
        icon1.addFile(u":/images/images/icons8-maximize-window-26.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.restore_button.setIcon(icon1)

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.restore_button)

        self.close_button = QPushButton(self.top_right_boutton)
        self.close_button.setObjectName(u"close_button")
        self.close_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.close_button.setStyleSheet(u"")
        icon2 = QIcon()
        icon2.addFile(u":/images/images/icons8-close-window-26.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        self.close_button.setIcon(icon2)

        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.close_button)


        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.top_right_boutton)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main_header)

        self.main_body = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_body.setObjectName(u"main_body")
        self.main_body.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.main_body.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.main_body.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.main_body)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.left_side_menu = QFrame(self.main_body)
        self.left_side_menu.setObjectName(u"left_side_menu")
        self.left_side_menu.setMaximumSize(QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.left_side_menu.setStyleSheet(u"QFrame{\n"
" background-color:#000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
" padding: 20px 10px;\n"
" border: none;\n"
" border-radius: 10px;\n"
" background-color: #000;\n"
" color: #fff;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"  background-color:rgb(0,92,157);\n"
"}")
        self.left_side_menu.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.left_side_menu.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_side_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_7 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(u"pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-home-24.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 30px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setIconSize(QSize(22, 16))

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-account-32.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 30px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-rain-sensor-30.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 26px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QSize(22, 16))

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.pushButton_3 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(u"pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-rain-sensor-30.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 26px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)

        self.pushButton_4 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(u"pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-rain-sensor-30.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 26px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)

        self.pushButton_5 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(u"pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/icons8-rain-sensor-30.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 26px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)

        self.pushButton_6 = QPushButton(self.left_side_menu)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(u"pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet(u"background-image: url(:/images/images/apps_printer_15747.png);\n"
"background-repeat: none;\n"
"padding-left: 31.5px;\n"
"background-position: center left;\n"
"\n"
"")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)


        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.left_side_menu)

        self.center_main_items = QFrame(self.main_body)
        self.center_main_items.setObjectName(u"center_main_items")
        self.center_main_items.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.center_main_items.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.center_main_items.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.center_main_items)

        self.right_menu_side = QFrame(self.main_body)
        self.right_menu_side.setObjectName(u"right_menu_side")
        self.right_menu_side.setMaximumSize(QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.right_menu_side.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.right_menu_side.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.right_menu_side.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.right_menu_side)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main_body)

        self.main_footer = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_footer.setObjectName(u"main_footer")
        self.main_footer.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.main_footer.setStyleSheet(u"\n"
"QFrame{\n"
"\n"
" background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
" background-top-color: sold 1px rgb(0,0,0);\n"
" }")
        self.main_footer.setFrameShape(QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.main_footer.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main_footer)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.minimise_button.setText("")
        self.restore_button.setText("")
        self.close_button.setText("")
        self.pushButton_7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Accueil", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Compte", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u" Capteur1", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Capteur2", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Capteur3", None))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Capteur4", None))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Imprimer", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

In main code I'm trying to add some functionality like reducing or enlarging the window. I'm also trying to close the window, and move the window with the cursor, and so in my main function I want to add the events of the buttons, especially "Capteur" (which means sensor) and by pressing this button I want to display a graph that shows data from an air pressure sensor.

main code:

```
import sys
import platform
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QPropertyAnimation, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt, QEvent)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import os
from random import randint
import matplotlib


from ui_ihm import Ui_MainWindow


############################################ global variable################################
Window_Size=0;


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        

        ## UI ==> INTERFACE CODES
        #####################################################################################

        ## REMOVE TITLE BAR
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)


        ## DROP SHADOW EFFECT
        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(20)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(0)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(0)
        self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 60))
        self.ui.centralwidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow) 

       


        ######################### les evenements des boutton restore, reduir, fermer############

        self.ui.minimise_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
        self.ui.close_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.ui.restore_button.clicked.connect( lambda:  self.restore_or_maximize())
        #self.ui.bouton_cap1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.graph_cap)


        ##self.ui.dropShadowFrame.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
        ##self.ui.dropShadowFrame.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

        #######################################################################
        # move window avec la souris 
        def moveWindow(e):
            #detect if the wondow is normal size
            if self.isMaximized()==False:
            # move window only if the window is minimized
                # if the left button mouse is clicked
                if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
                    # move window
                    self.move(self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
                    self.clickPosition=e.globalPos()
                    e.accept()





        ########################################################################
        # evenement de clique sur la souris pour faire bouger la fenetre
        self.ui.main_header.mouseMoveEvent=moveWindow

        


        # show window gui ############################################################
        self.show()
    

    # fonction pour  reduir ou a agrandir la fenetre 
    def restore_or_maximize(self):
        global Window_Size
        win_status = Window_Size
        if win_status==0:
                Window_Size=1
                self.showMaximized()
        else:

                Window_Size=0
                self.showNormal()


    ##### add mouse event to the window #################################################
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        ## get the currut  position  of the mouse
        self.clickPosition=event.globalPos()
    
    #def graph_cap(self):

    

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    #window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you try and extract the relevant portion of your code. That will increase the chance of you getting help and advice. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also please be more careful with formatting and avoid trying unnecessary emphasis styling (the point of bold/italic is to emphasize a portion of the text, if you do that on a whole block it just becomes useless and quite annoying). Read more carefully the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) guides.